# Некорректно работает функция, вызванная посредством ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который вызывает php-функцию посредством ajax-запроса. Функция выполняется, но остальные нужные для работы запроса функции игнорируются.

PHP:

```
  if(isset($_POST['action']) && function_exists($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        switch($action) {
            case 'findPopularDirection':
                findPopularDirection();
            case 'getSpecialOffersList':
                getSpecialOffersList();
            default:
                die('Access denied for this function!');
        }
    }

function getCurrencyCode($country_code) { // функция определения валюты по стране проживания
    $currency_codes = array(
        'Украина' => 'UAH',
        'Россия' => 'RUB',
        'Беларусь' => 'BYN',);

    if(isset($currency_codes[$country_code]))
        return $currency_codes[$country_code];

    return 'USD'; // Default to USD
}

function currencyToIcon($country_code) {
    if($country_code === 'USD') { return '$'; }
    else if($country_code === 'UAH') { return '&#8372;'; }
    else if($country_code === 'RUB') { return '&#8381;'; }
    else if($country_code === 'BYN') { return 'BYN'; }
}

function LocateUserGeo() {
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    global $ch;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.travelpayouts.com/whereami?locale=ru&callback=useriata&ip=" . $user_ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: 6c2df703e0853f2e0137761ea6d58305"));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response = json_decode($response = preg_replace('/^[^\(]+\((.*)\)$/', '$1', $response), true);
}

function findPopularDirection() {
    $geo = LocateUserGeo();
    $link = "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/city-directions?origin=" . $geo['iata'] . "&currency=" . getCurrencyCode($geo['country_name']);
    global $ch;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: 6c2df703e0853f2e0137761ea6d58305"));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $popular = json_decode($response, true);
}
```

ajax-запрос:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/php/popular.php?action=findPopularDirection',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Суть ошибки состоит в том, что при вызове функции посредством php она правильно компонует ссылку `"http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/city-directions?origin=" . $geo['iata'] . "&currency=" . getCurrencyCode($geo['country_name'])`. Но в случае вызова функции посредством ajax функция `getCurrencyCode()` игнорируется. Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: хотелось бы поподробнее. Что происходит после выполнения функции findPopularDirection?...ведь результаты её работы никуда не сохраняются...Зачем использовать глобальные переменные? Можно посмотреть код функции getCurrencyCode? где объявляются и инициализируются переменная $geo? что вы ожидаете получить в ответе и что на самом деле выводится?

Comment: @МихаилРебров ссылка к api должна генерироваться в зависимости от страны клиента и выбранного курса валют. Собственно, в переменной $geo хранится код страны клиента, а функция getCurrencyCode превращает код страны(например, RU) в валюту - RUB. И по идее должна быть ссылка http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/city-directions?origin=IEV&currency=UAH, но API возвращает мне результаты запроса так, словно origin и currency были пустыми(используется локация MOW и валюта USD). То есть, то о чём я и говорю - не выполняются другие функции.

Comment: может быть getCurrencyCode правильно выполняется, просто она не видит данных из $geo, потому что она где то неправильно объявлена или инициализирована? в данном скрипте много кода? его не страшно будет показать чтобы проще было найти проблему?

Comment: @МихаилРебров обновил код с PHP.

Comment: сейчас я попробую его выполнить и скажу если найду что

Answer (score 4):

Общие моменты:

- в конце кода каждого кейса ставьте break, если не хотите чтобы они выполнялись подряд друг за другом
- старайтесь не использовать глобальные переменные, потому что это зло
- благодаря использованию глобольной переменной $ch у вас например смешивались параметры cURL и несмотря на то, что параметры для запроса вы устанавливали в разных функциях они смешиваются, т.к. они работают с одной и той же переменной
- в вашем примере curl_exec($ch) возвращал TRUE, а результат запроса выводил в стандартный поток вывода, поэтому все дальнейшие действия над $response были бессмыслинными
- однако где-то это сыграло вам на руку...например в свитче результат запроса волшебным образом транслировался из запроса отосланного из php в результат его работы...и здесь вам придётся сделать выбор.
- для того чтобы получить ответ на запрос в виде строки при вызове curl_exec($ch) Вам необходимо установить параметр CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, который отвечает за то куда выводить результат запроса(по умолчанию в стандартный поток вывода или же в качестве результата вызова метода)

и отдельно...вот так вот лучше не делать, даже несмотря на то что это работает...это очень сложно читать

```
return $response = json_decode($response = preg_replace('/^[^\(]+\((.*)\)$/', '$1', $response), true);
```

так на мой взгляд гораздо приятнее:

```
return json_decode(preg_replace('/^[^\(]+\((.*)\)$/', '$1', $response), true);
```

Учтём всё написанное:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && function_exists($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'findPopularDirection':
            findPopularDirection();
        case 'getSpecialOffersList':
            getSpecialOffersList();
        default:
            die('Access denied for this function!');
    }
}

function getCurrencyCode($country_code) { // функция определения валюты по стране проживания
    $currency_codes = array(
        'Украина' => 'UAH',
        'Россия' => 'RUB',
        'Беларусь' => 'BYN',);

    if(isset($currency_codes[$country_code]))
        return $currency_codes[$country_code];

    return 'USD'; // Default to USD
}

function currencyToIcon($country_code) {
    if($country_code === 'USD') { return '$'; }
    else if($country_code === 'UAH') { return '&#8372;'; }
    else if($country_code === 'RUB') { return '&#8381;'; }
    else if($country_code === 'BYN') { return 'BYN'; }
}

function LocateUserGeo() {
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.travelpayouts.com/whereami?locale=ru&callback=useriata&ip=" . $user_ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: 6c2df703e0853f2e0137761ea6d58305"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    return json_decode(preg_replace('/^[^\(]+\((.*)\)$/', '$1', $response), true);
}

function findPopularDirection() {
    $geo = LocateUserGeo();
    $link = "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/city-directions?origin=" . $geo['iata'] . "&currency=" . getCurrencyCode($geo['country_name']);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: 6c2df703e0853f2e0137761ea6d58305"));
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    //return $popular = json_decode($response, true);
}
```

но и тут есть свои минусы:

- в методе findPopularDirection я не стал править до конца...я не проставил там параметр curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE) и результат вывода транслируется в std_out.
- но такая штука вводит в заблуждение потому что непонятно откуда выводится результат и почему
- параметр лучше проставить, но тогда вам придётся переделать SWITCH в самом начале...т.к. он вызывает методы, но не принимает результатов их работы и не выводит их клиенту

получится как-то так но с остальными кейсами придётся разобраться самому

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && function_exists($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'findPopularDirection':
            $response = findPopularDirection();
            echo json_encode($response);
            break;
        case 'getSpecialOffersList':
            getSpecialOffersList();
            break;
        default:
            die('Access denied for this function!');
    }
}

function getCurrencyCode($country_code) { // функция определения валюты по стране проживания
    $currency_codes = array(
        'Украина' => 'UAH',
        'Россия' => 'RUB',
        'Беларусь' => 'BYN',);

    if(isset($currency_codes[$country_code]))
        return $currency_codes[$country_code];

    return 'USD'; // Default to USD
}

function currencyToIcon($country_code) {
    if($country_code === 'USD') { return '$'; }
    else if($country_code === 'UAH') { return '&#8372;'; }
    else if($country_code === 'RUB') { return '&#8381;'; }
    else if($country_code === 'BYN') { return 'BYN'; }
}

function LocateUserGeo() {
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.travelpayouts.com/whereami?locale=ru&callback=useriata&ip=" . $user_ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: 6c2df703e0853f2e0137761ea6d58305"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    return json_decode(preg_replace('/^[^\(]+\((.*)\)$/', '$1', $response), true);
}

function findPopularDirection() {
    $geo = LocateUserGeo();
    $link = "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/city-directions?origin=" . $geo['iata'] . "&currency=" . getCurrencyCode($geo['country_name']);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: 6c2df703e0853f2e0137761ea6d58305"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return json_decode($response, true);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за полезные советы с PHP. Я внёс соответствующие правки в свой код! Но ajax-запрос теперь вообще не выводит ничего в консоль.

Comment: одну секунду, сейчас проверю последний вариант

Comment: для начала попробуйте заменить переменную $_POST на переменную $_REQUEST

Comment: вы используете $.ajax вместо $.post, и запрос может отправляться с помощью метода GET

Comment: Да, действительно. Заменил `$_POST` на `$_REQUEST` и всё заработало. Спасибо, что не пожалели времени и написали столь ёмкий и полезный текст. С Наступающим!

Comment: С Наступающим! Удачи вам! :-)

Comment: и это ещё не конец! :-D...getCurrencyCode один чёрт USD возвращает

Comment: У меня всё нормально, показывает UAH: `Object { success: true, data: Object, error: null, currency: "UAH" }`

Comment: но это исправилось изменением кодировки файла, так что в коде всё норм! ещё раз с наступающим! ;-)

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: Не за что) Удачи и доброй ночи)